aero thermofluids Bernoulli equation
Oil of relative density 0.8 flows at a volumetric flow rate of 0.216m3/s through a falling pipe which tapers gradually in the direction of flow. At point A in the pipe the diameter is 600mm and the gauge pressure is 0.84bar. Calculate the gauge pressure at point B which is 3.6m below A, the pipe diameter at B being 300mm.

How about you show your attempt and we offer any relevant correction? aka we are not a homework completion service.

Your question title should explain the subject matter of the question. All questions are requesting help so that's redundant. So is the "Thanks in advance" which doesn't belong in the title and on SE sites you thank afterwards by upvoting useful answers and accepting one that solves the problem.

@SolarMike there's plenty of similar examples on this platform as to what I have put. just needing some help mate, not trying to be difficult

@Transistor just trying to manage work load and couldn't find answer, please be aware im new on this platform so thanks for your help.

There are plenty where the poster's input has been requested...

If you show your attempt at applying Bernoulli equation, people here will be more willing to help you. As it is now, you just seem to someone else to solve your homework for you.

@TomášLétal thank you, not my intention at all, but appreciate it could have been interpreted that way. added my workings

solved it now. appreciate all your help.

Your approach is correct.
The continuity equation
$Q = A_A v_A = A_B v_B$

A_a area of section A
A-b area of section B

$$ v_A = \frac{Q}{A_A} = \frac{0.216}{0.2827} = 0.764 , m/s $$
$$ v_B = \frac{Q}{A_B} = \frac{0.216}{0.0707} = 3.055 , m/s$$
So far your calculations are ok.
Plugging into the Bernoulli equation.
$$P_A + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_A^2 + \rho g h_A = P_B + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_B^2 + \rho g h_B$$

$  P_A = 0.84 , bar = 84,000 Pa$
h_a=0M
h_b=-3.6M

Plugging the values in and simplifying.
$$84,000 + \frac{1}{2} \times 800 \times (0.764)^2 + 800 \times 9.81 \times 0 = P_B + \frac{1}{2} \times 800 \times (3.055)^2 + 800 \times 9.81 \times (-3.6)$$
Simplifying
$$84,000 + 233.6 = P_B + 3732.4 - 28224 \quad \rightarrow 84,233.6 = P_B - 24491.6 \quad P_B = 84,233.6 + 24491.6 \ \rightarrow P_B = 108,725.2 , Pa \quad \rightarrow P_B = 1.087 , bar $$
We get
$P_B = 1.087 , bar$

thank you so much Kamran!

@aerostudent1, please click on accept the answer so it can be used for future users as well.
